Query Error in SQL: : No matching signature for operator CASE; all THEN/ELSE arguments
WITH RECURSIVE EducationClassification AS (
SELECT 
    code,
    name_en,
    description_en,
    education_classification_code,
    historic_ind,
    source,
    effective_date,
    expiration_date,
    CAST(level AS INT64) as level,
    parent,
    code AS level_0_code,
    name_en AS level_0_name,
    NULL AS level_1_code,
    NULL AS level_1_name,
    NULL AS level_2_code,
    NULL AS level_2_name,
    NULL AS level_3_code,
    NULL AS level_3_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(level AS INT64) = 0 THEN 'Root'
        ELSE 'Leaf'
    END AS node_type
FROM 
    input_table
WHERE 
    CAST(level AS INT64) = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    i.code,
    i.name_en,
    i.description_en,
    i.education_classification_code,
    i.historic_ind,
    i.source,
    i.effective_date,
    i.expiration_date,
    CAST(i.level AS INT64),
    i.parent,
    r.level_0_code,
    r.level_0_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(i.level AS INT64) = 1 THEN i.code
        ELSE r.level_1_code
    END AS level_1_code,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(i.level AS INT64) = 1 THEN i.name
        ELSE r.level_1_name
    END AS level_1_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(i.level AS INT64) = 2 THEN i.code
        ELSE r.level_2_code
    END AS level_2_code,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(i.level AS INT64) = 2 THEN i.name
        ELSE r.level_2_name
    END AS level_2_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(i.level AS INT64) = 3 THEN i.code
        ELSE r.level_3_code
    END AS level_3_code,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(i.level AS INT64) = 3 THEN i.name
        ELSE r.level_3_name
    END AS level_3_name,
    'Leaf' AS node_type
FROM 
    input_table i
INNER JOIN 
    EducationClassification r ON CAST(i.parent AS STRING) = r.code)
SELECT * FROM EducationClassification;

Query error: No matching signature for operator CASE; all THEN/ELSE arguments must be coercible to a common type but found: INT64, STRING; actual argument types (WHEN THEN) ELSE: (BOOL STRING) INT64 at [45:9]
This is a query in Google BigQuery.
I am unable to identify where the exact problem is? Please help me fix this query? The BigQuery or any LLM GPT engine is unable to give me appropriate response?

What is on line 45?   Can you hilight where the error is?  You will likely also have to paste the schema of the table to diagnose correctly.

The error is self-explanatory and it is related to the CASE statement on line 45:
CASE 
    WHEN CAST(i.level AS INT64) = 1 THEN i.code
    ELSE r.level_1_code
END AS level_1_code,

The field i.code is a string, while r.level_1_code is an INT64. It is mandatory for these two fields to have the same data type in a CASE statement. You should cast them to the same data type.
